# Change column names in Pandas Dataframe from a list

Tags: python, pandas

Is is possible to change Column Names using data in a list?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1.0, 2.3,0.2,0.53], [2, 3.35, 2.0,0.2,0.65], [2,3.4, 
       2.0,0.25,0.55], [3,3.4,2.0,0.25,0.55], [1,3.4,2.0,0.25,0.55], 
       [3,3.4,2.0,0.25,0.55]], 
       columns=["ID", "A", "B","C","D"])\
       .set_index('ID')
```

I have my new labels as below:

```
New_Labels=['NaU', 'MgU', 'AlU', 'SiU']
```

Is possible to change the names using data in the above list? My original data set has 100 columns and I did not want to do it manually for each column.

I was trying the following using df.rename but keep getting errors. Thanks!

Comment: `df.columns[1:] = New_Labels` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) is a formally more correct approach. You just have to provide a dictionary that maps your current columns names to the new ones (thing that will guarantee expected results even in case of misplaced columns)

```
new_names = {'A':'NaU', 'B':'MgU', 'C':'Alu', 'D':'SiU'}
df.rename(index=str, columns=new_names)
```

Notice you can provide entries for the sole names you want to substitute, the rest will remain the same.

Answer (score 14):

You can use this :

```
df.columns = New_Labels
```

Answer (score 6):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1.0, 2.3,0.2,0.53], [2, 3.35, 2.0,0.2,0.65], [2,3.4, 
       2.0,0.25,0.55], [3,3.4,2.0,0.25,0.55], [1,3.4,2.0,0.25,0.55], 
       [3,3.4,2.0,0.25,0.55]], 
       columns=["ID", "A", "B","C","D"])\
       .set_index('ID')
New_Labels=['NaU', 'MgU', 'AlU', 'SiU']
df.columns = New_Labels
```

this will make `df` look like this:

```
     NaU  MgU   AlU   SiU
ID                       
1   1.00  2.3  0.20  0.53
2   3.35  2.0  0.20  0.65
2   3.40  2.0  0.25  0.55
3   3.40  2.0  0.25  0.55
1   3.40  2.0  0.25  0.55
3   3.40  2.0  0.25  0.55
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) answer is fine, but it's mainly for mapping old→new names. If we just want to wipe out the column names with a new list, there's no need to create an intermediate mapping dictionary. Just use [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) directly.

---

## [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html)

To set a list as the columns, use [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) along `axis=1` (the default `axis=0` sets the index values):

```
df.set_axis(New_Labels, axis=1)

#      NaU  MgU   AlU   SiU
# ID                       
# 1   1.00  2.3  0.20  0.53
# 2   3.35  2.0  0.20  0.65
# 2   3.40  2.0  0.25  0.55
# 3   3.40  2.0  0.25  0.55
# 1   3.40  2.0  0.25  0.55
# 3   3.40  2.0  0.25  0.55
```

---

Note that [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) is similar to modifying `df.columns` directly, but [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) allows method chaining, e.g.:

```
df.some_method().set_axis(New_Labels, axis=1).other_method()
```

Theoretically, [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) should also provide better error checking than directly modifying an attribute, though I can't find a concrete example at the moment.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It allows you to method chain, which means you don't have to create a temporary `df` to modify the attribute. `.rename` isn't very natural to use as it requires the previous column names.

Answer (score 3):

```
df.columns = New_Labels
```

Take care of the sequence of new column names.